# PrimeNG p-listbox background color

Tags: angular, typescript, listbox, primeng

I am trying to use the PrimeNG's p-listbox component for the first time.  A simple p-listbox seem to work, but when I added the ng-template, things are not working correctly.  So, my example p-listbox control displays both a string and the id in the list fields.

string (id)

```
<p-listbox #nav id='nav' name='nav' [options]='incidents'
    (onClick)='onNavChange( $event )' multiple='false'
    [listStyle]="{'max-height':'400px'">
    <p-header>Selected Id: {{ model ? model.IncidentId : 'none'}}</p-header>
    <ng-template let-incident pTemplate='item'>
        <div class='ui-helper-clearfix'>
            <span>{{incident.IPAddress}} ({{incident.IncidentId}})</span>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</p-listbox>
```

The typescript component code is as follows:

```
    //
    model: Incident;
    selectedModel: Incident;
    incidents: Incident[] = [
        new Incident( 1, '23.48.167.129', 'arin.net'),
        new Incident( 2, '180.97.158.175', 'ripe.net'),
        new Incident( 3, '103.46.138.150', 'arin.net'),
        new Incident( 4, '145.239.212.60', 'ripe.net')
    ];
    // 
    onNavChange( event ): void {
        // Allow direct call
        const item = <Incident>event.option;
        console.log( `${this.codeName}.onNavChange, Selected item: ${item.IncidentId}` );
        this.model = item;
        //
    }
```

The incident class, I just put at the bottom component:

```
class Incident {
    constructor(
        public IncidentId: number,
        public IPAddress: string,
        public NIC: string
    ) { }
}
```

The problem is that once an item is selected, then all of the items are the selected item color.  So, all 4 items are the same color and if one un-selects the listbox, one cannot tell which item was selected.

I am using version 9.0.1 PrimeNG.

Sample image of p-listbox component.
[image: p-listbox component]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

primeng p-listbox required options data with structures base of `{label:any,value:any}[]` and will set the class base of the selected option value in case of two option has same value both of theme will have the highlight class, your options don't have a value so the unique is undefined or all key has the same value .

so the best case is just map the options data to `{label:any,value:any}[]`

```js
ngOnInit(){
        this.options = this.incidents
            .map(item => ({label:item.IPAddress , value:item.IncidentId}))
}
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-listbox)

another options is  by set `optionLabel` and `dataKey` , check the  [documentation](https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/listbox)

Comment: Thanks, the simple format with optionLabel worked fine.  So, it has to be in SelectItem interface format.

Comment: yes most of the primeng components work base of `SelectItem` interface 